# How to bind NSObject <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate> in Monotouch?

Tags: c#, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind this library for bluetooth.

I have an interface in objective-c code, defined as shown.

`@interface OSWristBand2 : NSObject <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>`

Now, both delegates are classes from CoreBluetooth library. How am I supposed to bind this? You obviously can't inherit from two classes in C#.

Comment: Not sure if it would work but maybe weak delegate would satisfy the interface needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
public interface OSWristBand2 : ICBCentralManagerDelegate, ICBPeripheralDelegate
{
}
```